An intuitive molecular picture of Bernoulli’s principle?
I’m trying to grasp Bernoulli’s prediction that pressure decreases when
air passes from a wide pipe into a narrow pipe, as in a Venturi meter,
from the standpoint of molecules.  I think in both pipes the molecules
of air have the same average energy and the same average momentum.
This momentum is transferred to any surface (eg: the pipe walls) and
acts as pressure.  If there is no temperature increase, when the molecules
are passing through the narrow pipe and thus moving faster, this means
that more of their intrinsic motion is directed along the pipe’s axis.  In
the X direction.  Thus, less of their molecular motion can be directed toward
the pipe walls and so less momentum is transferred, along the Y and Z axis,
toward the walls of the narrow pipe.  Hence less pressure.  This follows
from conservation of energy.
Qualitatively, is this a valid point of view?

The velocity of the fluid goes up when enters a smaller passage, due to conservation of mass, so how is the average momentum of the particles conserved? Moreover, if you agree that the average momentum went up as well, then you need to ask yourself what force led to that. The answer will be the gradient of pressure, which will help you understand that indeed, the pressure in the narrow pipe must be smaller than in the wide pipe

There is an earlier related question: "Why does Bernoulli's principle work?" The top voted answer there accounts for the effect first in terms of energy, and next in terms of Newton's second law. The macroscopic view is the way to go; it facilitates intuitive understanding. I expect: attempting to account for the effect in terms of molecular motion is a dead end.

Your thinking seems to be wrong.
Example 1: Suppose we have a straight and equal diameter pipe, and we artificially accelerate the water inside. At the same time, the velocity of the water is the same, but the pressure of the water at different pipe sections is different. In this example, the speed of water is the same, but the pressure is different, which contradicts your explanation.
Example 2: Suppose we have two straight and equal diameter pipes, but the velocity of water in these two pipes is different, one with a higher velocity and the other with a lower velocity. However, the pressure of water in both pipes can be the same, both at atmospheric pressure. Assuming the pipe is ideal and has no resistance. In this example, the speed of water is different, but the pressure is the same, which contradicts your explanation.
